# Как менять цвет блоков div на js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

Есть блок в котором разные цвета (панель выезжает с правой стороны), при клике на блок меняется цвет панели с верху.

Как сделать, чтобы можно было менять цвет отдельно для верхнего и отдельно для бокового блока с последующим сохранением в Local Storage?

Весь код на: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/cLc36xwr/)

Js:

```
  var $box_menu = $('.box_menu');
//var $box_left = $('.box_left');

$('.metro li').each(function(){
    var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  $(this).click(function() {
      $box_menu.css('backgroundColor', color);
  });  
});
```

Comment: какой все-таки конечный результат должен быть? кликнули по цвету и поменялись цвета у всех панелей? или выбрали панель - и применили цвет только для нее?

Comment: @Grundy Цвет нужно менять для одной панели, а затем для другой. Конечный результат,  хочу сохранить цвета в `local storage`.

Comment: а как вы хотите определять для какой панели меняется цвет сейчас?

Comment: @Grundy Именно в этом и заключается вопрос, ибо делать отдельный контейнер с цветами и код `js`,  для каждого блока `div` нет смысла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вы можете сделать `select` в котором будет выбор, для чего мы сейчас меняем цвет. А при клике на цвет уже подставлять цвет к выбранным элементам. В `value` у `options` мы например можем сразу хранить класс или `id` элемента для которого меняете цвет. Пример решения https://jsfiddle.net/cLc36xwr/3/

```
var $currentPanel = $('#currentElement');

$('.metro li').on('click', function (event){
 var $panel = $($currentPanel.val());
 //Не очень хорошо хранить значение прямо в span, лучше использовать data-color аттрибут или как-то еще хранить.
 $panel.css({
  backgroundColor: $(event.currentTarget).find('span').html()
 });
});
```

Comment: Я не храню название цвета в `span`, я только так для примера написал название цвета, даже если удалить `span`  цвет все равно будет выбираться.

Comment: В CSS его тоже хранить не очень, выносите такую логику, лучше без хардкода т,к, вдруг вам понадобиться селектор сменить, а у него фон уже другой. Просто в целом bad way

Comment: Можете привести пример, как правильно хранить цвет в `data-color`. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: все тоже самое, только цвет берете в data-color. в с span  пишите <span data-color="#ffcc00">click me</span> а в js логике меняете backgroundColor: $(event.currentTarget).attr('data-color')

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо держать набор цветов где-то в одном месте, напр. в массиве. И программно рисовать палитру.

Посмотреть, есть ли что-то в localStorage:

```
if( localStorage.getItem('menu.bgcolor')) { 
   // если есть, то поменять блоку цвет на сохранённый.
```

Сохранить выбранный по клику цвет в LS:

```
localStorage.setItem('menu.bgcolor', color);
```

Для выбора блока сделал в каждом цвете при наведении появляющиеся стрелки: в левой части стрелка влево, меняет левый блок. Справа стрелка вверх, меняет цвет «меню».

Убрал из стилей повторное указание цветов палитры, и переписал JS так:

```
var $box_menu = $('.box_menu');
var $box_left = $('.box_left');

// цвета задаём лишь один раз:
var colors = ['#A87B51','#56DEA7','#FF7659','#F8CD36','#F26175','#5CA7DF','#C86466','#9E7AC2'];

// рисуем палитру программно
$('ul.metro').append(
  colors
    .map((c,i) => ('<li style="background-color:'+c+'"><span>' +c 
        +'</span>'
      +'<div class="e-pb" data-block="left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-2x"></i></div>'
      +'<div class="e-pb" data-block="menu"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up   fa-2x"></i></div>'
        +'</li>'))
    .join("\n")
);
// слушаем события сразу всем
$('.e-pb').on('click', (e) => {
        var block = $(e.currentTarget).data('block');
    var color = $('span', $(e.currentTarget).parent()).text();
    localStorage.setItem(block + '.bgcolor', color);
    if( block === 'menu') $box_menu.css('background-color', color);
    else if( block === 'left') $box_left.css('background-color', color);
  }
);

// есть ли что-то в localStorage?
if( localStorage.getItem('menu.bgcolor'))
    $box_menu.css('background-color', localStorage.getItem('menu.bgcolor'));
if( localStorage.getItem('left.bgcolor'))
    $box_left.css('background-color', localStorage.getItem('left.bgcolor'));
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/r2ac3mjm/5/)

Вариант, мне кажется, неплох, но только для двух блоков. Если их больше, придётся придумывать что-то другое. Может, как предлагает @DStrokov, в два клика: выбирать, каким блоком рулим, и потом цвет. Ещё можно сделать цвета draggable – чтобы их можно было брать и тащить на блок, который поменять. Но это, кажется, менее удобно – требуеися больше точных движений мышкой.

Comment: ага, а вопрос был как для второго это так же применить. то есть можно было менять отдельно для верхнего и отдельно для бокового блока

Comment: обновил ответ. Вообще такой интерактив удобнее переписать с React : )